# Задание валидного двумерного массива

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть работающий код задания двумерного массива:

```
field=[]
for i in range(8):
        block = []
        for j in range(8):
             block.append('X')
        field.append(block)
```

Выгялдит не очень, но он работает! Суть проблемы в том что при "не красивой" инициализации все списки отдельные объекты и когда мы делаем изменение в ячейке меняется только она. 
Как сократить, чтобы код был более "питонистичным", но и сохранить правильную изменяемость ячеек (функциональность)?

Что-то вроде

```
field = [['X']*8]*8
```

Но так при изменении поля, меняются все поля по координате из-за того что все ссылаеться на один список.
Хочу чтобы при field[2][2] = 'O' изменялась только ячейка [2][2], а не весь столбец

`field[2][2] = 'O'`

```
['X', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X']
['X', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X']
['X', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X']
['X', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X']
['X', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X']
['X', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X']
['X', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X']
['X', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X']
```

Пытался использовать [:], list, но результата нет

Comment: ну так просто вместо `self._field=[]` оставьте `_field=[]` Что это за self у вас вообще ?

Comment: это все в классе находится, суть же не в этом
я сейчас self везде уберу, код от этого не заработает)

Comment: уберите `field = [['X']*8]*8` и будет в одном месте только менять

Comment: или вы `field = [['X']*8]*8` вот этой строчкой просто пытались код сократить ?

Comment: @ИгорьИгоряныч да, именно ей сократить и пытался

Comment: Вы читали поваренную книгу python?

Comment: @HasmikGaryaka, вы просто так интересуетесь?) Я например нет, а что, ее прочтение обязательно, чтобы знать Python?)

Comment: не читал, но читал Hitchkers guide и документацию, какой смысл это спрашивать?

Comment: Я только что скачал. Для массивов там используется nympy.array

Comment: @HasmikGaryaka Да, можно и его, но именно здесь используется через два списка, и сократить надо было не прибегая к сторонним библиотекам. Я просто не видел чтобы в генераторы засовывали генератор до этого, вот :(

Comment: Никто не запрещает засовывать, можно было догадаться.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
L = [['X' for n in range(8)] for n in range(8)]
```

Comment: Да, это оно, спасибо!

Comment: А, понял проблему: Вот так будет проще чуток: `[['X']*8 for i in range(8)]`